# What is the math behind offset slider in exposure adjustment on photoshop?

Tags: image, math, image-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to understand the formula or the math behind the "**offset** slider".
As found in `Image -> Adjustments -> Exposure`.

I'm working on a project for detecting shadows in an image and I need to understand how this slider work.
I spent a week comparing photos and pixel values but I couldn't understand the formula behind it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching for an answer to this question: it can be found in this web article: https://geraldbakker.nl/psnumbers/exposure.html

This is an in-depth study of the Exposure adjustment in Photoshop, including a lot of math and explanation what happens behind the scenes!

Key points discussed:

- Exposure is designed for working in 32-bit
- A short summary of 8-, 16- and 32-bit coding in Photoshop
- The meaning of gamma corrections
- All formulas for the Exposure sliders (Exposure, Offset, Gamma), in 8-bit and in 32-bit mode (they are different)
- Some oddity with the eyedroppers on the Exposure window

Lots of math, pretty technical, but very exhaustive.

Comment: Hi, Gerald, and welcome to StackOverflow. Since rot-link can happen, would you mind summarizing some of his key points? It would make your answer more valuable to the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

Formula for exposure:  `out = in * 2^(exposure);`

Formula for offset:  `out = in + offset;`

Formula for gamma:  `out = in ^ 1/gamma;`

note that these assumes floating point values, and is not clipping on 1.0 with no curve correction, you might want to apply correction by `in ^= 2.2` and `out ^= 1/2.2` before and after applying the above formulas, respectively.